# socket.io multiplexing not working -Angular/ExpressJs/Socket.io

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a messaging app using angular in front and ExpressJs/socket.io backend.
I am using two namespaces for example "socket1" and "socket2"

```
const socket1 = io(URL + "socket1")
const socket2 = io(URL + "socket2")
```

Usually this should create one websocket, and it does when the app is loaded for the first time, but after disconnecting and reconnecting . It creates 2 different websockets with different ids.

I read the documentation of [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/namespaces/index.html)  and none of the cases that can cause this apply to my code.

Comment: Why do you need two sockets instances?

Comment: the messaging interface is just a part of a bigger app, i use one socket/namespace when i am not using the messaging part of the app for notifying when a message is received and the other one when the user is using the messaging part

Comment: What I recommend is not to cache the user for the socket id, rather, for a unique id of the user, such as the token.
Pass it a parameter, or initialize the socket, rather than in the onconnect, in an event that you emit from the front